# Getting JSON in Post Method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json, post, asp.net-web-api2

I am working in MVC5 with c# and 
I am posting data to Web-api2 server in JSON like this:

```
function SendSms() {
    var studentData = {
        Id: "4",
        ClientId: "2",
        NoOfRecipient: "3",
        Msg: "This is a test",
        Numbers: [
            { Number: "988888888", Id: "3"},
            { Number: "988888787", Id: "5"}
        ]
    };
    console.log(JSON.stringify(studentData));

    $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost/ProductsApp/api/SmsClients",
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: JSON.stringify(studentData),
        dataType: "json",
        processData: true,
        success: function (data, status, jqXHR) {
           console.log(data);
        },statusCode: {
            201 /*Created*/: function (data) {
               console.log("created");
            }
        }
    })
    .fail(
    function (xhr, textStatus, err) {
        console.log("Error");
    });
}
```

and accepting the JSON like this:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post(SmsData smsData)
{
    //code to be performed after getting Post
}
```

And My SmsData Model Is like this:

```
public class SmsData
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ClientId { get; set; }
    public int NoOfRecipient { get; set; }
    public List<Numbers> Numbers { get; set; }
    public string Msg { get; set; }
    public DateTime SentDate { get; set; }
}

public class Numbers{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public long Number { get; set; }
}
```

But I get the Numbers Property of the smsData Null. Why is this so... Why is the Numbers Property coming null. How can I Get the the Numbers

Comment: Have you tried using an array instead of a list for the Numbers field?

Comment: I believe the 'List<T>' won't work for the Json parser. Try changing it to 'Numbers[] Numbers'

Answer (score 0):

Using array instead of a list should help but you can also try to set the "traditional:true" parameter when executing the ajax call.

$.ajax({
        cache: false,
        **traditional: true,**
        type: "POST",